# Programmatically loading a ES6 module with Traceur in web page

Tags: ecmascript-6, traceur

I have been using Traceur to develop some projects in ES6.  In my HTML page, I include local Traceur sources:

```
<script src="traceur.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
```

and if I have a module in the HTML afterwards like:

```
<script type="module" src="foo.js"></script>
```

Then Traceur loads in that module, compiles it and everything works great.

I now want to programmatically add an ES6 module to the page from within another ES6 module (reasons are somewhat complicated).  Here was my first attempt:

```
var module = document.createElement('script');
module.setAttribute('type', 'module');
module.textContent = `
    console.log('Inside the module now!');
`;
document.body.appendChild(module);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as Traceur does not monitor the page for every script tag added, I guess.

How can I get Traceur to compile and execute the script?  I guess I need to invoke something on either 'traceur' or '$traceurRuntime' but I haven't found a good online source of documentation for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can load other modules using ES6 `import` statements or `TraceurLoader` API for dynamic dependencies.

Example from [Traceur Documentation](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/LanguageFeatures#modules)

```
function getLoader() {
  var LoaderHooks = traceur.runtime.LoaderHooks;
  var loaderHooks = new LoaderHooks(new traceur.util.ErrorReporter(), './');
  return new traceur.runtime.TraceurLoader(loaderHooks);
}
getLoader().import('../src/traceur.js',
    function(mod) {
      console.log('DONE');
    },
    function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
);
```

Also, System.js loader seems to be supported as well

```
window.System = new traceur.runtime.BrowserTraceurLoader();
System.import('./Greeter.js');
```

Comment: Shouldn't `import` return a promise rather than taking callbacks?

Comment: These examples reference JS files / URLs.  I want to programmatically construct a module (in JS) and have it loaded in and executed.

Comment: @Bergi you are right. But I took this code from documentation and so it seems no longer actual

Comment: @codedread Why do you need a programmatically-generated module? Usually, it can be with `eval()` that contains `// @sourceMap` comment at the end

Comment: As I stated, the reasons are complicated :)  - I don't think eval() will work because I need it to go through the Traceur compiler (to resolve and load other modules that this one imports)

Comment: Okay, so good luck, maybe some more advanced Traceur users can help you

Comment: The getLoader() code example is embarrassingly old, I apologize and will fix it. The `import` and `System.import()` examples are correct.  The System.import()` call returns a promise and thus the load is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic module loading is a (not-yet-standardized) feature of `System`:

```
System.import('./repl-module.js').catch(function(ex) {
  console.error('Internal Error ', ex.stack || ex);
});
```

To make this work you need to `npm test` then include BrowserSystem

```
<script src="../bin/BrowserSystem.js"></script>
```

You might also like to look into https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs as it has great support for browser loading.

BTW the `System` object may eventually be standardize (perhaps under a different name) in the WHATWG: http://whatwg.github.io/loader/#system-loader-instance

Comment: Thanks John - after I build traceur-compiler, I don't seem to have a bin/BrowserSystem.js.

Comment: `npm test` will build it.